# "I give it to him who came first" vs. "to he who came first"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences, grammaticality, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is grammatically correct: “Let he who…” or “Let him who…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who)

Should the pronoun be "him" because it's the object (*gave it to him*), or should it be "he" because it is subject of the subordinate clause "he who came closest."

Also, what is "who came first" described as, grammatically?

I should know, but I don't, and it bugs me.

Answer (score 6):

The correct pronoun is *him*, because it is first and foremost the [indirect object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29) of the [main clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause) (*I gave it to him*), and should therefore be in the [accusative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case).

It's actually not the case that *him* is the subject of the [relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause) (*who came first*).  The subject of that clause is *who*.

Comment: According to Google Books, *let **he** who is without* has actually overtaken [let **him** who is without](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+he+who+is+without%2Clet+him+who+is+without&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) now. Contrariwise, *me and him* has eclipsed [I and he](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+and+he%2Cme+and+him&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3). These pronouns seem quite fluid at the moment.

Comment: I wonder what the deal is with *without* - *let **he** who* is significantly less popular than *[let **him** who](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+he+who%2Clet+him+who&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)*.

Comment: It's also largely confined to **he** - [no recent rise in](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let+they+who%2Clet+them+who%2Clet+she+who%2Clet+her+who&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) popularity for **her** or **them** that I can see.

Comment: I think 'let he' has a more dramatic and formal feel to it, like old or biblical english. It doesn't sound correct by today's grammar though.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but **let he** sounds really wrong to me. You do not say **let he go**, but **let him go**, don't you?