# More issues with the predicate nominative

Tags: grammatical-case

In comparison to German, English is very "situational" with its predicate nominative (see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140985/issues-with-predicate-nominative)).

Suppose the rule is that the predicate nominative is only ever applied for sentences like the following:

> It was I, who did that.

then it would be very logical if it were

> "Who was that."
>
> "That was I."

- Is this spoken by anyone?
- Is this considered correct by the ardent defenders of the predicate nominative?
- If the answers are "No." wouldn't it make sense to say that there is no such thing in the heart of the English language after all?

Comment: There _is_ no such thing in the heart of the English language. It has been bolted on by pedants, and taught to some people.

Comment: Right. "Predicate nominative" is a phrase borrowed from Latin, which actually does have such a construction and a nominative case to go with it. English just has predicate adjectives (_Mary is tired and dirty_) and predicate nouns (_They are all lawyers_), both of which require auxiliary _be_, but has no cases to mark them with. Only personal pronouns have any vestiges of case marking left, and it's rare to use pronouns as predicates; pronouns are for things that are already understood and can be abbreviated, rather than for being the predictate of a clause.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler wrote in a potentially ephemeral comment:

> Right. “Predicate nominative” is a phrase borrowed from Latin, which actually does have such a construction and a nominative case to go with it.
>
> English just has predicate adjectives (*Mary is tired and dirty*) and predicate nouns (*They are all lawyers*), both of which require auxiliary *be*, but has no cases to mark them with.
>
> Only personal pronouns have any vestiges of case marking left, and it’s rare to use pronouns as predicates; pronouns are for things that are already understood and can be abbreviated, rather than for being the predictate of a clause.