# "He who" as an indirect object

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects, indirect-objects

Is the following incorrect?

> Return it to he who gave it to you.

Presuming it is, how would I correct it?

(without resorting to saying "to the person who gave it to you," which is somewhat cheating in my mind because *the person* takes the same form as a subject and object, as opposed to *he* and *him*)

Comment: "Return it to him who is the object of the preposition *to*."

Comment: 'Everything comes to he who waits' sounds more plausible, less jarring, but is still incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One and the same person is serving both as object of the preposition *to* and as subject of the verb *gave.* Thus both subjective and objective pronoun forms come into play. It is part of the virtue or function of the relative pronoun, in this case *who,* to mediate such a shift in case. That frees the third-person masculine singular personal pronoun to assume the case appropriate to its role as object of the preposition *to,* which is *him.* The need for a subjective-case pronoun to be subject of the verb *gave* is filled by the relative *who,* which does here manifest its subjective-case form, *who,* as opposed to *whom.* (The case of the relative generally accords with its syntactic role within the relative clause, which here is as the subject of the clause.) Thus for formal edited written English the preferred form of your sentence would be

> Return it to *him* who gave it to you.

While the person to whom “it” is to be returned may be considered the indirect object of the verb *return* (“it” being the direct object), for purposes of determining pronoun case it is better considered as object of the preposition *to,* since Modern English has no separate dative case for indirect objects.

Comment: *Return* doesn't license an indirect object.  You can say, "Give him the book", but not "Return him the book".

Comment: @deadrat Sure it does. It's not so common now as it was down to the 20th century, but it's still to be found here and there.

Comment: @StoneyB "Not so common now" is a charming way to say "extinct."

Comment: 'Will you return me my book?' doesn't sound too extinct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: it's at least arguable that that is a benefactive _me_, like "make me a sandwich", and not an argument of "return".

Comment: @Colin Fine Whatever we call it and however it should be analysed (and I've seen treatments labelling benefactive objects as indirect objects), 'Will you return me my book?' is not extinct (though 'Return him the book' admittedly sounds less acceptable).