# Correct use of the verb in terms of pronoun and number

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, tenses

I'm an English student yet, and today I had this sentence and this question.
In the sentence:
*"I am a person that does not like routine but rather tries to maintain an overall healthy lifestyle."*

Why do we use the verb tense "tries" which normally agrees with he/she/it, but this is a first person sentence and how could I explain this?
This sentence is wrong or is right?

I think the sentence is wrong, because it should be:
" I am a person that do not like routine, but rather is trying to maintain an  overall healthy lifestyle."

I'm not sure about the right answers.

Comment: The first is better than the second.

Comment: @tinlyx answer is correct. Note to OP: If all of the verbs were to agree with “I”, the sentence would need to be “…but rather **am** trying…”

Comment: There's an [existing question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical) about "Remember me, who is/am your friend" which also discusses sentences such as "I am a person who likes apples". So if you are asking about agreement with first or third person, look at that. (It also depends on whether "is trying to maintain an overall healthy lifestyle" is part of the subordinate clause starting "that", or not - "I am a person that does not like routine, but I am trying to..." would be fine, with or without the second "I".)

Comment: [This closed question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362949/me-who-is-or-me-who-am) has more discussion on "me who is"/"me who am"

Answer (score 1):

The clause "that does not like routine but rather tries to maintain an overall healthy lifestyle" is for "the person". Hence the verb tense in "does" and "tries".