# he or she with their?

Tags: pronouns, agreement

I have a question about a sentence.

When writing for mass media, success goes to **he or she** who puts **their** most important info at the top of the story.

Should it be he or she paired with their?

Comment: Success goes to him or her...

Comment: This question is unclear--there are so many pronouns and so little punctuation that it's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: This is a question that is on a grammar test that I have to take.

Comment: Will someone correct it as they see fit?

Comment: When writing for mass media success goes to him or her who puts their most important info at the top of the story.

Comment: Would you add a comma after media? Would you put him or her instead of he or she? If you did put him or her, would you leave their?

Comment: @William Elliott: It's always ***he or she [who]*** in your context, not ***him or her***. Consider ***He who hesitates is lost***, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The preposition *to* requires objective case, surely? "Success goes to him who..."

Comment: @Andrew: Hmm. [It seems you're right](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Success+goes+to+him+who%22) (that's a claimed 35 instances of *Success goes to him who...*, but there's only one instances of the same with ***he***). In my example *He who hesitates is lost* he's a ***subject***, not objective case. I still don't like ***him*** in OP's context, but apparently that's just me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [It's not just you](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who), but Andrew Leach's answer is better for a grammar test.

Comment: Success on the grammar test goes to him who asks his instructor which answer will be considered correct.

Comment: He who asks his instructor which answer will be considered correct will experience success.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043639/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/he-or-she-versus-they) gives four valid alternatives:

1. I was taught to use the pronouns he, his, him, or himself to include both genders but this usage is now viewed in many quarters as sexist so I now avoid this usage.
2. You can use the wording ‘he or she’, ‘his or her’, etc.
3. If you can make the relevant noun plural then reword the sentence as necessary:

   If your **children** are thinking about a gap year, **they** can get good advice from this website.
4. Finally you can simply use the plural form even though it refers back to a singular pronoun.