# The use of they and those

Tags: they

I know variations on this have been asked before but I am still left doubtful about the use of they and those in these sentences.

It can only be understood by they who entrust their lives to it.

The most important lessons we learn are those that we can least explain.

Clarity would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Richard

Comment: "by they who" is wrong, according to the most upvoted answers to the following question: [Which is grammatically correct: “Let he who…” or “Let him who…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who)

Answer (score -1):

'They' is a personal pronoun and can be used only as the subject of the sentence or clause.
'Those' is a determiner of plural nouns and can be used in the sentence as the substitute or attribute of plural nouns.
That's why the phrase 'by they' is wrong.