# personal pronouns in object position but subjective case

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Why is this right?
Give the baton to **he** who is closest to you when you run by.
Does the case of the restrictive clause drive the case of the sentence object?

Comment: I'd say that accusative "him" is correct, not nominative "he".

Comment: [New American Standard Bible:](https://biblehub.com/nasb/john/8.htm) ***He** who is without sin among you, let him be the first to throw a stone at her.* [English Standard Version:](https://biblehub.com/esv/john/8.htm) *Let **him** who is without sin among you be the first to throw a stone at her.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is grammatically correct: "Let he who..." or "Let him who..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/which-is-grammatically-correct-let-he-who-or-let-him-who)

Comment: The pronoun in the OP's example is object of a preposition, not a subject, or object of a verb, so the imperative "Let he/him who ..." is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Joan Why did you choose to use "he" instead of "who(m)ever"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question you link to relates to the subsidiary clause's verb, and does not entertain the possibility of the relative pronoun's antecedent being in subject case.

Comment: @Rosie F The thread contains  'Another example in this area is the famous

_Let him who is without sin cast the first stone._ / 

_Let he who is without sin cast the first stone._

The prescriptive 'over-rule' is that he/him (who is without sin), which links the letting and the casting the first stone, has its case governed by the letting (ie is in the objective) rather than by the casting the first stone. But (though hits are surprisingly low) Google stats indicate the 'incorrect' choice occurs three times as often as the 'correct'. Will the rule change!?'

Comment: It's not the personal pronoun that is subject of the relative clause but the relative pronoun "who", which is neutral in respect of its antecedent, i.e. both accusative "him" and nominative "he" are possible. But since the pronoun is object complement of the prep "to", then "him" is correct.

Comment: Thanks you all for your reflections on this. I've since decided that the example is in fact "wrong," not "right," for the preposition must take its object (the accusative) "him" (as BillJ noted) and the relative pronoun clause must be driven by its own form (subj.-verb, etc., i.e., who is . . .). So: give the baton [to him] [who is closest to you when you run by.]  As for "Let him . . ." -- same "rules": him is the object of "let"; the nonrestrictive relative pronoun clause drives its own bus: who is without sin.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical/81369#81369).

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about this?

> Give the baton to he whom you trust.

It sounds worse to me than your example, so I'm guessing that you are right, and that "he" in your example is due to agreement in case with the "who" of the relative clause.

Comment: "[Give the baton] [to --> him] [whom <-- you trust].") Object of preposition in objective/accusative case; object of "trust" likewise.

Comment: Yes.  In accordance with your theory, "whom" should imply "him", at least when "him" is already in an object position.